# If $f$ is differentiable then how do we know that $f'$ is integrable?

Tags: analysis

If $f$ is differentiable then how do we know that $f'$ is integrable ?
This is used proof of integration by parts.

Comment: Note that integration by parts requires *continuously* differentiable functions.

Comment: @dxiv Technically, no, I believe you just need $f'$ to be Riemann integrable.

Comment: Famous counterexample (for Riemann integrability at least): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra's_function

Answer (score 2):

We don't know that it is integrable, even in the Lebesgue sense.  For example, if 
$$ f(x) = \cases{x^2 \sin(1/x^2) & if $x \ne 0$\cr
                 0 & if $x=0$\cr} $$
then $f$ is differentiable everywhere, but $f'$ is not integrable on intervals containing $0$.

In most applications, $f$ is assumed to be not just differentiable but continuously differentiable, i.e. continuity of $f'$ is assumed.